# Yii2 access rules (AccessControl) strange result

Tags: yii2, access-control

When i use such access rules

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
            ],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
            'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                echo 'Denied';
            }
        ],
    ];
}
```

The result is: logged-in users can see the page, but unlogged-in users can't see the page (it strange because the rule for unlogged-in user is the first and here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html we can read

> ACF performs the authorization check by examining the access rules one
>   by one from top to bottom until it finds a rule that matches the
>   current execution context.

So, why the first rule for unlogged-in users don't work, but the second rule for logged-in user works?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you wrote `rules` two times. As a result you get associative array with two identical keys. PHP allows add elements with the same keys into associative array but it leads to weird behavior. As far as I remember the latest declared element will have priority.

So your rules are actually are:

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'allow' => true,
        'roles' => ['@'],
    ],
],
```

That's why only logged-in users are allowed, everything is correct.

Should be changed to:

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'allow' => true,
        'roles' => ['?'],
    ],
    [
        'allow' => true,
        'roles' => ['@'],
    ],
],
```

But think logically about what you want - it doesn't make sense. Logged-in users can access all actions and guests can access all actions. So all users can access all actions within this controller. As a conclusion - for the current state you don't need declare any access rules and can just omit that.